# In JavaFX 8 how can I bind to a computed expression?

Tags: javafx-8

I apologize if this is a repeat (couldn't find one) or pretty simple.  I just can't find anything on it.

I would like to have a dynamic title on my primary stage based on values in a table.  However I can't seem to find a way to handle this without have to code it on an event listener.  I'd rather create a binding if possible.

Something like this:

```
primaryStage.titleProperty().bind("Open Items" + tableView.getItems().size());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
primaryStage.titleProperty().bind(Bindings.size(tableView.getItems()).asString("Open Items %d"));
```

or

```
primaryStage.titleProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> 
    "Open Items "+tableView.getItems().size(),
     tableView.getItems());
```

or

```
primaryStage.titleProperty().bind(new StringBinding() {
    { bind(tableView.getItems()); }
    @Override
    public String computeValue() {
        return "Open Items "+tableView.getItems().size();
    }
});
```

and probably many other ways...

Comment: Thanks!  I went with the first one.  Appreciate the quick reply.